# Getting path to Huffman Nodes

Tags: java, huffman-code

I am attempting to create a Huffman tree out of any file's byte[] and then zip it. To create the BitSequence, I create a HashMap of bytes and the corresponding string value that equals its path to its node. When working them out by hand, I am getting BitSequence lengths that are much longer than what my program is putting out. Here is my code that creates the HashMap of values, where bytes is the byte value for that node:

```
 public static HashMap<Byte, String> getPath(Node n)
  {
    HashMap<Byte, String> map = new HashMap<Byte, String>();
    buildPath(n, "", map);
    return map;


  }
  public static void buildPath(Node n, String s, HashMap<Byte, String> map) {
   if(n != null)
   {
     if (n.left != null){
      buildPath(n.left, s+"0", map);
   }

   if (n.right != null){
    buildPath(n.right, s+"1", map);
   }
   if(n.left == null && n.right == null)
   {
     map.put(bytes, s);
     return;
   }
   }
   return;
  }
```

I then go through the original byte array from the file and use the generated HashMap to append the Huffman path to a sequence that I will zip up with the Huffman tree itself, so that I can decode it later. Is there an error in the way I'm generating the path, or could my problem lie somewhere else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see your methods are static, so I assume the variable bytes is too. That won't put the byte value into your HashMap, and instead you'll keep putting null in there. Get rid of the statics, and then it should put the byte value into the map correctly. You can make it private and make a method like getByte() that returns it, or you can simply make bytes public and call it with whatever object you're using.